# Dynamic textfield created inside gridview cell gives value null while accessing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic

I have a gridview of 4 columns of which first 2 columns have ItemTemplate fileds ie dropdownlist and textfield remaining 1 column have dynamic created label and in last column two textfields within the cells 
Below is my code 
in Page_Load() function I am dynamically adding textfields and lables in gridview cell.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int subrows = 2;
        int rows = 2;
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
            Dt.Columns.Add("index", typeof(string));
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                DataRow Dr = Dt.NewRow();
                Dr["index"] = i;
                Dt.Rows.Add(Dr);
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = Dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            int c = 2;

            for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < subrows; k++)
                {
                    Label l = new Label();
                    l.ID = "lbl" + k;
                    l.Text = "" + "<br/>";
                    l.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

                    GridView1.Rows[j].Cells[2].Controls.Add(l);

                    Label lbl = (Label)GridView1.Rows[j].Cells[2].FindControl("lbl" + k);
                    lbl.Text = "jay" + "<br/>";
                    lbl.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

                    TextBox t = new TextBox();
                    t.ID = "txt" + k;
                    t.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

                    GridView1.Rows[j].Cells[3].Controls.Add(t);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And on Button2_Click() function I want to access the values of the fields withing gridview.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int subrows1 = 2;
        int rows1 = 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < rows1; i++)
        {
            DropDownList dl = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("DropDownList1");
            TextBox tx = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("TextBox1");

            for (int j = 0; j < subrows1; j++)
            {
                 Label l1 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("lbl" + j);
                 TextBox t = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("txt" + j);

            }
        }
    }
```

But I can only able to access the values of dropdownlist and textbox from first two columns which are ItemTemplate fields which are added using Edit Template. And When I try to access the values of the fields which are dynamically added in gridview give **null** value.

Markup file:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
            CellPadding="3" CssClass=" table table-bordered" 
            RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100%" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Field office">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem>--Select Field--</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Ahmedabad</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Ahmedabad-2</asp:ListItem>

                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Field Center ">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SS ">
                    <ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Productivity">
                    <ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate">
                    <ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
```

updated with markup file

Comment: Try putting the code to create the dynamic boxes in the [RowCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated(v=vs.110).aspx) event. The way WebControls bind (and read) data requires the controls to be present at a particular time in the lifecycle.

Comment: `why are you calling DataBind() in this fashion
`        GridView1.DataSource = null;
            GridView1.DataBind();` why not bind the grid after you fill the contents of your datatable..? redundant calls here I suggest that you debug that code and step thru and I bet you will see where you are making the mistake

Comment: ya @DJKRAZE sorry for my mistake I have updated the code, but still the same problem

Comment: show the Markup code as well perhaps you have some error in the markup that's being supressed

Comment: ok I see an Issue. how come you are trying to do the following 
` Label l1 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("lbl" + j);` the datagrid does not have a label control if your need to find the value or the `lbl.Text` then you can do FindControl or just assign the value of the text to a variable I am confused on what you are trying to do after looking at your MarkUp

Comment: under this ItemTemplate  `<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SS ">
                    <ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>`  I am adding label which is dynamically created and added to the grid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61511/discussion-between-jayesh-naik-and-dj-kraze).